# Cannot login Atlassian due to the issue in Load Scripts

Tags: javascript, atlassian-sourcetree

Tried to Login the Atlassian via **Chrome** but couldn't able to do it. Same happens for the browsers **Firefox**, **IE**. I'm using the latest version of the above-said browsers. Below is the screenshot of the error which I have got when trying to login.

[image]

Could anyone please help me with this?